# About the energy of electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, mass-energy, orbitals

According to Einstein the total energy $E=mc^2$.
Now my question is why don't their exist any orbits with fractional values such that they satisfy the above Einstein's equation, even though the electrons are absent in that fractional shells? Why don't their exist such fractional shells.

Comment: Why do you think the equation you quote has anything  to do with electron orbitals? That might help with answering your post, thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what your are talking about, as there exists a solution for  the hydrogen atom of the [Dirac equation](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node501.html) and it comes out with the same energy levels as the non relativistic one.

> This result gives the same answer as our non-relativistic calculation to order alpha^4

All of the relativistic relations are satisfied and nothing fractional appears .

Orbits belong to the [Bohr model](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Bohr.html) which was a first atempt at quantization, Quantum mechanics gives probability distributions , [orbitals.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html)

Comment: A small quibble: The energies of the Dirac Equation solutions are not quite identical to the Schrodinger solutions. Spin-orbit splitting are responsible for most of the differences.

Comment: @LewisMiller they fit the data, and the link I gave says they are the same up to alpha^4

Comment: Since both results are analytic, it is easy to compare them and indeed they are very close numerically as well as good fits to the experimental data..

Answer (score 0):

By fractional I assume you mean many other energies should be possible but for a given electron in a given atom (or molecule) the electron has wave properties which force it to adapt to certain orbits.  Similar to a guitar string ... it just plays one note (or harmonics of), so many wavelengths fit between the ends of the string.

In another atom type the energies levels will be different, so in that sense many different energies are possible for the different atoms/molecules.

Answer (score 0):

If electrons occupied a continuous range of fractional energy values around the nucleus of an atom, they would continuously lose kinetic energy, and eventually they would [fall into the nucleus](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Quantum_Mechanics/09._The_Hydrogen_Atom/Atomic_Theory/Why_atoms_do_not_Collapse).  This is because a charged particle undergoing acceleration around the nucleus would emit electromagnetic radiation until it lost all the potential energy of its "orbit" and fell into the nucleus.  The Universe as we know it could not exist.

Electrons in atoms, however, do not have both a definite mass and a definite trajectory around the nucleus.  They are quantum particles subject to the [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2013/nov/10/what-is-heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle).  They do not "orbit" the nucleus.  Their position is not determined by gravitational energy.  They have wave properties, and they occupy regions of space around the nucleus that accommodate specific wave lengths, or energy levels.

An electron's position in an atom is determined by the energy level of its electric charge, and the charge of the nucleus.  Electrons in an atom emit and absorb energy in specific packets of wavelength.  The space around a nucleus accommodates electrons of energy levels composed of these packets.  Fractional packets, or packets of fractional wavelength, do not exist at the scale of an electron.

[Planck's theory](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Plancks-quantum-theory-about) states that waves are composed of quanta of energy.  The space around a nucleus accommodates whole numbers of quanta.  [Louis De Broglie](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Quantum_Mechanics/02._Fundamental_Concepts_of_Quantum_Mechanics/De_Broglie_Wavelength) combined Planck's theory with Einstein's equation, which you cite, to derive the wavelength of electrons at various energy levels.  These are the wavelengths that occupy space around a nucleus.  Similar to [standing waves in any medium](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ewav.html), the space in an atom can accommodate only whole numbers of waves, not fractions.